# How to scrape a table you can only access via a menu in the page with Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use python and BeautifulSoup to scrape a table which is visible in the code only when I click in a menu in the page.

I can scrape the table that is visible by default when the page is first opened. So I tried the same technique using the id or the call of the page but I cannot get the text. Here is the page (you can chose the view with the menu on the top of the table):

https://www.tabtouch.com.au/racing/2018-12-26/mr/1.

I am interested in view 'Field'.  Here's my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://www.tabtouch.com.au/racing/2018-12-26/mr/1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
mytable = soup.find('table', {'id': 'client-side-view'})
thetable = mytable.text
print(thetable)
```

With `'table', {'id': 'race-results'}`, which is the table you can see when you open the page, it works well. The table I want is accessible with the view menu on the top of the table on the page, click on 'Field' to see it.

I would like the same result I had scraping the race-result table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use Selenium to click click through those menus:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import bs4
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.tabtouch.com.au/racing/2018-12-26/mr/1"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)


driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="race-results"]/thead/tr[1]/th[1]/race-betting-menu/div/p/a').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="race-results"]/thead/tr[1]/th[1]/race-betting-menu/div/ul/li[2]/a').click()

html = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

mytable = soup.find('table', {'id': 'client-side-view'})
thetable = mytable.text
print(thetable)
```